# How to get max value from string value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data like this.

```
1000/PST-FDI/XII/2016
999/PST-TGR/XII/2016
998/PST-TGL/XII/2016
997/PST-SPM/XII/2016
996/PST-SPG/XII/2016
995/PST-SMG/XII/2016
994/PST-SMD/XII/2016
993/PST-SLT/XII/2016
```

The format value of the serial no is "SequenceNo/BranchCode/Month/Year". I want to select the last sequence no on this year. I made already select top 1 * from table order by serialNo desc, but it show me 999/PST-TGR/XII/2016. I don't know why.

I try to make a function like this

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getFirstNumeric](
    @s VARCHAR(50)
)  
RETURNS int AS 
BEGIN

set @s = substring(@s,patindex('%[0-9]%',@s),len(@s)-patindex('%[0-9]%',@s) + 1) 
if patindex('%[^0-9]%',@s) = 0
    return @s
set @s = substring(@s,1,patindex('%[^0-9]%',@s)-1) 

return cast(@s as int)
end
```

also it show for me 999/PST-TGR/XII/2016. Or because I made DESC so it comes late latest word 'PST-TGR' ?? so how to noticed just the sequence no based on the current year ?

Comment: what is column format of ID ? serialno ?

Comment: do you mean the column data type ? if yes, it is varchar(50)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because string ordering is hapening where `999` comes before `1000` in descending order

Try this

```
Order by cast(left(col,charindex('/',col)-1) as int) desc --,cast(right(col,4)  as int) desc
```

`LEFT/RIGHT` return type is `Varchar/Nvarchar` based on input. So we need to do a explicit conversion to `INT` to get the ordering right

Comment: Thank you for replying. But it's still show 999/PST-TGR/XII/2016

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT top 1
   [YourColumn]
 FROM [YourTable]
order by 
left([YourColumn], charindex('/', [YourColumn]) - 1)  asc
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. But it's still show 999/PST-TGR/XII/2016

Comment: I created a dummy table and inserted your data and when i run that script my output is  1000/PST-FDI/XII/2016

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

Using Substring :

```
             select * from ( select * ,
             cast(left(  
             (substring(Colname, patindex('%[0-9]%', Colname), 
             len(Colname))), patindex('%[^0-9]%',   
             (substring(Colname, patindex('%[0-9]%', Colname), len(Colname))) ) - 1)as int)  as serailID
              from Tablename
             )a      
              order by serailID desc
```

Check [Demo](http://rextester.com/WJH30704)
.

Using Function :

```
            SET ANSI_NULLS ON
            GO
            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
            GO
            create FUNCTION [dbo].[getFirstNumeric](
                @s VARCHAR(50)
            )  
            RETURNS int AS 
            BEGIN

            set @s =      left(  
                 (substring(@s, patindex('%[0-9]%', @s), 
                 len(@s))), patindex('%[^0-9]%',   
                 (substring(@s, patindex('%[0-9]%', @s), len(@s))) ) - 1)

            if patindex('%[^0-9]%',@s) = 0
                return @s
            set @s = substring(@s,1,patindex('%[^0-9]%',@s)-1) 

            return cast(@s as int)
            end

            select *, dbo.getFirstNumeric(columnname) as serailno1
            from TableName
            order by dbo.getFirstNumeric(serailno1) desc
```